# Cannot get partition to boot

Tags: osx, kali-linux, live-usb

I partitioned a 64 GB USB drive to make a Kali Linux live USB, but it's not booting from my MacBook Pro. The command I used to write the iso into the partition is:

```
sudo dd if=kali-linux-2017.1-amd64.iso  of=/dev/disk3s3 bs=1m
```

also

[image: here is the output from the diskutil list command]The partition I want to boot from is #3. Any insights as to why it is not booting?

Comment: If your parition is APPLE_HFS formatted that's going to be an issue, it needs to be FAT32 - see http://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-install - also please post text next time, not pictures

Comment: I just reformatted the partition and used sudo dd if=kali-linux-2017.1-amd64.iso  of=/dev/disk3s3 bs=1m to put the iso in it. Is now says it is "Microsoft Basic Data" under type. Still not booting from it.

Comment: Are you using the right disk? Because your screenshot shows the device as being disk2. Follow the directions on the link I gave you

Comment: I used the command from that link to copy the iso into the disk and yes I used sudo dd if=kali-linux-2017.1-amd64.iso  of=/dev/disk2s3 bs=1m          Does it matter that this is a partition from a USB as opposed to an unpartitioned USB?

Answer (score 0):

You have to press ALT during 5 seconds or more to get the boot menu.
Also your partition have to be FAT32.
Check if your "of=DEVICE" is the correct one instead of using device/partition.

Comment: I formatted to FAT but still not booting.